# Query to linked Oracle tables in ODBC error when criteria refers to control

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

When querying an Oracle linked table using a hard coded-date as the criteria (like `#12/06/2012#`), the query takes less than 1 second to return data.
When I replace the date criteria by `Forms!Formx!ctlRunDate`, the query takes ages and eventually reaches the ODBC timeout without providing a result.
I have tried using CDate() or typing the expression in the query parameters without any improvement.
Any suggestion ?
I am using Oracle ODBC. If I do the same with Microsoft driver for Oracle, no problem !

Comment: Can we assume that just switching to Microsoft's Oracle driver for the whole project is something you'd rather not do?

Comment: @GordThompson  The Oracle driver is imposed by the orgamisation, otherwise I wouldn't bother :-/